# Using two deep cycle 12 V batteries to create a 12 V circuit and a 24 V circuit

Tags: circuit-design, dc

I have two 12 V deep cycle batteries in my boat. I would like to create a 24 V circuit for my 24 V trolling motor and a 12 V circuit for my fish finder. Without purchasing an additional battery, is there a way I can create a 24 V circuit and a 12 V circuit that can be on simultaneously from the two 12 V batteries?

My thought was connect the two in series to create the 24 V circuit and connect the TM leads to the positive of the 1st battery and the negative of the 2nd battery. Then for the fish finder, connect the leads to the positive and negative of the 1st batt. Is this feasible?

[image]

As a follow-up, is there a possibility to safely charge these batteries without disconnecting the circuits?

Comment: Do you have access to two 12 V chargers?

Comment: @winny I have a dual battery 12V charger (it has two pairs of positive and negative leads). My concern is if I connect one pair to each battery, will it charger properly when batteries are connected in series? And will it have any negative effect on the other devices on the circuit?

Comment: Should be no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection shown will work. I personally would prefer a common ground but for a fish finder, I wouldn't be too worried. The only part you need to keep in mind is one of the battery will drain faster then the other. I don't know the size of your batteries nor the current consumption of your fish finder. It might not be significant. But if it is, you could run out of power way sooner then you expect due to the internal resistance of the batteries. Regarding the charging, if you plan on using a 24V charger, I would discourage you because both of your cells won't be equally charged. If you plan using a 12V charger, and charging each individually, I don't think it will be an issue, but it really depends on the circuit inside the motor.

Finally, the one issue I see with this setup is when starting your electrical motor, you could loose power to your fish finder. Depending on the circuit inside the motor, their could also be a spike when stopping it. I'm not sure it will be an issue, but it it a possibility.

Bottom line, I think your setup will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

My son has a 24V DC system and we needed 12 V DC for some things.

So, we got a quality 24V DC to 12V DC converter to do this which avoids any issues of draining one battery more than the other.

Comment: Definitely thought about that option. Might be the safest in the long run. I just wanted to see if it was possible without spending extra $.